# Looking for a network tester that can measure the speed of one cable

Tags: networking, testing, network-speed

I'm looking for a network tester that is able to measure the speed of one network cable (up to 1000 MBit).

I wasn't able to find any thing useful via google because most of the network tester are either made for just testing the connection of each wire or for tests within an existing network. I need one that is just having two female RJ45 connector to connect both ends of one network cable to it, then sends some data from one end to the other and indicates if the speed is at 1000 MBit, 100 MBit or below.

Comment: I think you may be attacking your problem from the wrong angle. Can you provide more info on what your trying to achieve? There are many more variables to consider than the network cable when talking about speed from node to node.

Comment: Also, Cat6 and Cat5e don't actually peak at 1000MBit / 100Mbit, and its not a good sole indication of expected real world throughput, either (as there is a lot of other variables as previously mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the frequency-response testers I have seen is a primary unit, with a daughter unit on the other end, that way they're usable both for "test single cable" and "test longer cable run". If "two ports, single unit" is a definite must-have, I certainly have not seen one.

Comment: No, I don't care if the device does have two parts.

Comment: @Martin: In that case, I suspect Fluke have one or more suitable devices in the USD 1000+ cost range

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [Fluke Networks](http://www.flukenetworks.com/fnet/en-us/), but for most just knowing the cable being used (Cat6, Cat5e), distance traveled, and having the switches that support are all you need.

Maybe you can elaborate on your needs?

Comment: Fluke CableIQ would be my choice for this task.

Comment: I second the cableIQ units we have them as a standard part of our tool kits. Fluke Networks gear is rock solid stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [iperf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/)?

Answer (score -1):

You can use qualification testers that perform tests to decide whether an existing cabling link will support the requirements for “Fast Ethernet” (100BASE-TX), Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP), or Gigabit Ethernet.